# jQuery: add class to sibling rows columns of same index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I've created function to find columns which contains number, then add class to them and to the next columns before code find an empty column. I also want to add class to the columns below (next rows but columns of same index) but I can't solve it. I've tried .parent() method but I'm stuck and I don't know what i'm doing to be honest... Here's my code

```
  $("table tbody tr td").each(function () {
    var num = $(this).text();
    if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
      $(this).addClass('word-' + num).nextUntil('td:empty').addClass('column-' + num);
    }
  });
```

And here's image to show what i want to do (red fields).[image]

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you provide your html and possibly add an additional table manually showing how you want the end result? As the question is now, its difficult to understand what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Here's my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5yzLftu0/
Example, number 1 has class word-1, and the same class is added to the next td in the same row. But i don't know how to add for example word-3 class to te td below number 3. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `if` statement, you could add something along the lines of:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yzLftu0/4/)

```
var indexed = $(this).index() + 1; // Get column number
var row = $('tr').has(this); // Current row
row.nextAll('tr').each(function(e) {
  var cell = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + indexed + ')');

  if(cell.text().length) {
      cell.addClass('word-' + num);
  } else {
      return false; // End loop if word is finished
  }

});
```

**Bonus**

If you want to style where words intersect (have two classes attached that start with "word-", you could do something like:

```
/* Intersection */
[class^='word-'][class*=' word-'] {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, that's what I wanted :)

```
  $("td").each(function () {
    var num = $(this).text();
    if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
      $(this).addClass('word-' + num).nextUntil('td:empty').addClass('word-' + num);
      var indexed = $(this).index() + 1;
      var row = $('tr').has(this);
      row.nextAll('tr').each(function () {
        var cell = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + indexed + ')');
        if (cell.text().length) {
          if (cell.find("[class*=word-]")) {
            cell.attr('vertical', 'word-' + num);
            cell.addClass('word-' + num);
          } else {
            cell.addClass('word-' + num);
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

I want to add "vertical" attribute, to the columns, which already has horizontal class, am I doing it good or wrong?